# Allowing WPF application to write to an XML file

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml

I have developed a WPF application and set up a deployment project. The installer works perfectly and so does the application, until it tries to do a entry in an XML file. These file act as an XML database for the application and are included in Application folders. Where am i going wrong. Do i need to assign some kind of privileges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, noting is wrong with the app.

You have to read documentation. You are *NOT SUPPOSED TO WRITE INTO THE APPLICATION FOLDER* since Windows NT4 or something. There are special folders to write into, and a method to get them. On normal modern windows the app folder is write protected for normal users, as it should be. It is the program folder.

Move your data over to the APPDATA folder, into a subfolder for your database.

Start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx for documentation.

Read the Windows guideleines for programming for the windows platform. There are a number of "do" and "do not do" there. Writing into the applications folder is one of the first "do not do".

Comment: Thanks buddy. But how can i make sure that this installs on Application Data folder ?? ...

Comment: Got that buddy. I added an User Application data folder to the deployment project and moved the files there. If this is not the way then let me know...
But i am having one problem with this way. The class are not able to use the file as i dont how should i provide the address : Right now its like this : Xml.Load(@"Ledgers.xml")

Comment: There is a meethod to get your application data folder. USE THE LINK TO THE DOCUMENTATION AND LOOK AT THE EXAMPLE. SImple. .NET has methods for this.

Comment: Thanks.... I did that, it was easy...just added an User Application Data folder to the deployment project and its done. But i am wondering how can i tell the application the address to those files. Right now its `Xml.Load(@"Ledgers.xml")` . What should i do to get this right on every other computer, as i cannot handcode every install

Comment: Again, you dont have to. ASK WINDOES WHERE IT IS. What is so hard in actually going to the link i provided and scroll down to the example? you dont WANT to? News: dont do it, dont solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, jsut a last note. If you get more complex drop the deployment project and go for WIX.... deployment projects are NOT a good way to deploy more than trivial softawre, they hide al ot too much of how MSI files are supposed to work. Wix / Votive does better, and is MS supported open source.